# USB 2.0 not working

Tags: windows-7, usb-2, supermicro

Whenever I plugin a USB memory device in one of my USB ports Windows 7 (32-bit) tells me *this device can run faster*. I tried several devices and all ports.

I found that the device manager doesn't list an **Enhanced** Universal Host Controller.

I tried removing all USB Host controllers and they automatically installed again but nothing changed.

How can I enable USB 2?

I have a [SuperMicro C2G41](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Core2Duo/G41/C2G41.cfm) motherboard.

Comment: Have you tried installing the chipset drivers from the SuperMicro site?

Comment: Yes, downloaded the installer. It ran through the wizard and said me everything was installed. I guess if it didn't require a reboot it detected that my system is up to date and didn't actually install anything?

Comment: Have you checked your BIOS to see if there are any options for USB? A few motherboards do have some obscure settings. Have you tried different cables?

Comment: Didn't touch the cabling. Didn't open my machine (desktop PC). I'll check the BIOS options now...

Comment: No I meant the USB cables you are using to connect the devices.

Comment: Oh, ok didn't use those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the correct drivers are installed then it it is worth checking in the BIOS as some motherboards have an option in the BIOS to choose the USB mode (on this motherboard it would support USB 1.1 or USB 2.0)

Comment: You were right James. BIOS had an option "Enable USB 2.0 controller" which for some reason was switched off.